# Excel AND Statement with Dates and Strings

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My worksheet has two columns: purchase date, replace.  I need to identify those with a purchase date of fewer than 3 years and a string value of replace. If they meet these criteria I would like it to change the value of the Replace column with Review.

I tried the following:  =IF(AND(=L3<=TODAY()-1095),"TRUE","FALSE")

Comment: you wouldn't be able to change the value of replace with review, you would have to add a 3rd column and have the formula output review if it found matches for your cases.

Comment: It is always helpful to provide some sample data with expected output.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the second condition in your `AND`:

```
=IF(AND(L3<=TODAY()-1095, M3="Replace"),"TRUE","FALSE")
```

note: I assumed the replace column is column `M`, adjust the formula to the correct one

Comment: Whoops, I completely forgot the second condition.